# Looking solutions for a custom dropdown with dynamic form drop down option

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I'm using angular 5 and primeng version 6 for my current project. I'm trying to implement a drop down component.But I need to implement dynamic option with form on it,like the image provided.that form(drop down option) has some function on it.

I have tried this, but no luck.

```
<select >
  <option value="1">
    <form>
       <label>AO Drink Bottel</label>
       <label>$2.00</label>
       <button>+</button>
       <input>0</input>
       <button>+</button>
       <button>add</button>
    </form>
  </option>
  <option value="2">
    <form>
       <label>AO Drink Bottel</label>
       <label>$2.00</label>
       <button>+</button>
       <input>0</input>
       <button>+</button>
       <button>add</button>
    </form>
  </option>
<option value="3">
    <form>
       <label>AO Drink Bottel</label>
       <label>$2.00</label>
       <button>+</button>
       <input>0</input>
       <button>+</button>
       <button>add</button>
    </form>
  </option>
</select>
```

is this possible?. any better solution for this?

**Image of the dropdown**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use @angular/cdk/overlay to build this component.

```html
<!-- This button triggers the overlay and is it's origin -->
<input (click)="isOpen = !isOpen" type="text"  cdkOverlayOrigin #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin" >

<!-- This template displays the overlay content and is connected to the button -->
<ng-template
  cdkConnectedOverlay
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen"
>
  <ul class="example-list">
    <li><form style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
       <label>AO Drink Bottel</label>
       <label>$2.00</label>
       <button>+</button>
       <input type="text" >
       <button>+</button>
       <button>add</button>
    </form></li>
    <li><form style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
       <label>AO Drink Bottel</label>
       <label>$2.00</label>
       <button>+</button>
       <input  type="text">
       <button>+</button>
       <button>add</button>
    </form></li>
    <li><form style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
       <label>AO Drink Bottel</label>
       <label>$2.00</label>
       <button>+</button>
       <input  type="text">
       <button>+</button>
       <button>add</button>
    </form></li>
  </ul>
</ng-template>
```

Example :
https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/examples

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOBPd.png)

Comment: can you suggest a primeng solution with this?

Comment: @HashanLiyanage94 I ma ot sure with PrimeNG but try.[https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5.2.7/#/overlaypanel](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5.2.7/#/overlaypanel)